# How to declare an Int that has a minimum and a maximum?

Tags: java, int, mouse, slick2d

The title says it all, in my Slick2D state, I'm tracking the MouseX and MouseY coordinates and I want the X to be in between 8 < MouseX < 944 and the Y between
8 < MouseY < 573. Here is the concerned bit of code (if needed...):

```
int xpos = Mouse.getX();
int ypos = Mouse.getY();
```

Comment: I dont't get your question, what exactly do you want

Comment: Are you saying that you want the values of `MouseX` and `MouseY` to be in those ranges, or for the mouse cursor itself to be constrained to those ranges (i.e. you can't move the cursor outside the rectangle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
int xpos = Math.max(Math.min(Mouse.getX(), 944), 8);
int ypos = Math.max(Math.min(Mouse.getY(), 573), 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a `Setter` to achieve this :

```
public void setXPos (int x){
    if (x < 8){
        this.xPos = 8;
    } else if (x > 944){
        this.xPos = 944;
    } else {
        this.xPos = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you very rapid answer, after trying to implement this in my code, java seems to reject `public void setXPos(int x)` telling me that `void is an invalid type for the variable setXPos` but after I take out the void, more errors arrive telling me to remove `int` and add a `;` to finisht the variable declaration. (Sorry if I'm doing this terribly wrong, frankly I have never really used setters and getters).

Answer (score 0):

`int` and `Integer` are both unable to bind the value to a range. You'll need to program this logic yourself.

How and where you should implement the logic is dependent on what you are trying to achieve.